# In every DFS run on $G$, in every step of DFS, the $G_{\pi}$ is a forest

Tags: algorithms, graphs, depth-first-search

Studying for my finals. So I'm reading the "Introduction to Algorithms (Third Edition)" book. In the DFS section there is the following section:

> Depth-first search yields valuable information about the structure of a graph. Perhaps
> the most basic property of depth-first search is that the **predecessor subgraph
> $G_{\pi}$ does indeed form a forest of trees**, since the structure of the depth-first
> trees exactly mirrors the structure of recursive calls of `DFS-VISIT`. That is,
> $u=v.\pi$  if and only if `DFS-VISIT(G,v)`  was called during a search of $u$’s adjacency
> list. Additionally, vertex $v$ is a descendant of vertex $u$ in the depth-first
> forest if and only if $v$ is discovered during the time in which $u$ is gray.

I'm trying to prove the following statement for myself:

> In every DFS run on $G$, in every step of DFS, the $G_{\pi}$ is a forest.

This question is coming from a booklet published for studding for the finals (without solutions).

I understand the logic behind why it true (with the help of the statements from the book). But I struggle of writing a "formal proof" which shows the correctness of it. Do I need to use induction to prove it (since I need to show it for *every step*). How to prove this statement formally?

For the completeness of the question, the $G_\pi=(V,E_\pi)$ is the following graph:
$$
E_\pi=\{(\pi[v],v)\,:\,\pi[v]\neq NULL \wedge v\in V\}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use induction. You will assume that $G_\pi$ is a forest, and you want to prove that $G_{\pi'}$ is also a forest, where $\pi'$ is $\pi$ after one step of the DFS algorithm.

The key point, is that a forest is a graph without cycles. So basically, you want to show that no new cycles where created in the last step. To prove this, you will want to have a statement similar to this:

Assume towards contradiction that $G_{\pi'}$ contains a cycle. Hence, the new node $u'$ that was added to $G_{\pi}$ in order to create $G_{\pi'}$ must be a part of the new cycle (since $G_{\pi}$ was a forest). Therefore, there must be some node $u\in G_\pi$ such that $\pi(u)=u'$, but this is impossible since it would mean that $u'$ would have been already visited in $G_{\pi}$, but this is impossible since $u'$ was visited only after $G_{\pi}$ was constructed.

Comment: Thank you! If $G_\pi$ does not have cycles, it means that it's a forest or I need to add something after that?

Comment: A tree is a connected acyclic graph. A forest, is just like a tree, but it doesn't have to be connected. Therefore, a forest is just an acyclic graph

Comment: Ok got it. Another last question - for the base of the induction, can I say the following? - Base: for $k=0$ (where $k$ is the DFS step), the graph $G_\pi$ consists of $|V|$ vertices with no edges so each vertex is a tree and $G_\pi$ is a forest consisting of $|V|$ trees.

Comment: @vesii yes, that is totally valid